# Why does Megatron have teeth?

Tags: transformers, megatron

Is there any reason for him to have teeth, or is it just a purely cosmetic choice from the design team for a more fierce look ? As far as I know he's the only transformer to have this feature in the movies, but I reckon the animated shows must have others, right ?

Comment: For chewing things. Duh.

Comment: http://tfwiki.net/wiki/Teeth

Comment: Shockwave also has teeth in the movie; http://tfwiki.net/mediawiki/images2/1/1a/DOTM-Shockwavecloseup.jpg

Comment: And Grimlock; https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/e8/52/c7/e852c7233376410f875c2e264d891e6b.jpg

Comment: I would say that it is purely aesthetic.  Much in the same way that there is no reason for some of the transformers to have articulated mouths (their speech is produced via a speaker and not by blowing air through an articulated tunnel like we do), the teeth are equally superfluous.

Comment: Oh I never noticed that about Shockwave, nice @Valorum
and yeah I figured it was for the aesthetics but maybe it was for some form of transformation. Oh well ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ thanks ! :)

Comment: Why does he turn into a handgun sized for a 300-foot giant?

Comment: @Buzz They're robots in disguise.  No one said it a *good disguise.*

Comment: All the better to eat you with, my dear.

Comment: You really need to specify *which* Megatron you are talking about, as there have been many versions over the years (comics, toys, TV shows, movies).